# How do I watch Youtube videos without Flash on Safari?

Tags: safari, adobe-flash, youtube

Is there a way to watch Youtube videos without Flash installed on Safari?

If not, are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a preference thing on YouTube to select HTML5, but they've reorganized the page so many times since I last tracked it down that I have no idea where it is now.

Instead, I have ClickToFlash installed (it's under "Most Popular" in the Safari Extensions Gallery); open its preferences (Safari Preferences... > Extensions) and you can tell it to always use HTML5 for YouTube and other sites that support HTML5 in place of Flash.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, most YouTube videos are also available as HTML5 videos. You need to sign in to YouTube and join the HTML5 trial -- see http://www.youtube.com/html5 for details.

Comment: You say "most" and that's what I'm seeing - some work, some require Flash. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

I use the [FlashToHTML5](http://www.joris-vervuurt.com/page9/page9.php) Extension, works great!

> FlashToHTML5 replaces the CPU and memory hogging YouTube Flash Player with a HTML5 player.
>   Not only will it look nicer, you will also notice that your computer will run cooler and faster. If you use a laptop, you will also notice that the battery life of a fully charged battery will increase.

Answer (score 1):

FlashToHTML5 appears to be very buggy almost broken with YouTube and Safari 6.0.2. The recently re-written Safari plugin [YouTube5](http://www.verticalforest.com/youtube5-extension/) is much better but only works with YouTube, Vimeo, and Facebook.

> A custom designed HTML5 player to replace the usable, but very limited built-in player.
>
> - Support for Vimeo and Facebook video.
> - The ability to switch video
>   resolutions within the player, without having to access Safari’s
>   preferences.
> - Support for downloading videos from YouTube and
>   Facebook.
> - A fully functional volume control, rather than just a mute
>   button.
> - Support for displaying the video’s title, author, and source,
>   in a video overlay, along with a link back to the video’s page on
>   YouTube, Vimeo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling Flash, Youtube no longer worked on Safari. Turns out, I had left ClicktoPlugin active, and that somehow confused the site. Disabled it (i.e. just running plain Safari) works fine.

Wrote this in case others with legacy settings might experience the same. Check your Safari > Settings > Plugins

Answer (score -2):

These plugins should also work with Safari+Ninjakit:

http://isebaro.com/viewtube/

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/169665

Comment: Answers should be more than just a link. Can you please explain the contents of your link so that your answer can stand alone in the event that your link becomes invalid?

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding information.